# The Signin Name Displayed Does Not Actually Exist In Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I'm doing some tests with a domain join script/program (which also does profile mapping), which means that I've been repeatedly joining/unjoining this test server to the domain (and in the process mapping local profiles to domain accounts).

The problem: I just unjoined the server from the domain (again). The server is in a workgroup. There are no other local accounts beside the local administrator account. I want to logon with the local administrator account, but the local administrator account is not being displayed at the signin screen. Specifically, there is only one signin name showing, and it is under my **domain account's display name** for some reason (e.g. "Smith John"). Since the server is not joined to a domain, this does not make sense.

It occurred to me that since I am doing some profile mapping tests, maybe the display name from my domain account was mapped to the local administrator account. However, if this is the case, I should be able to logon with this account using the local administrator password, but I cannot. For the record, I am unable to logon using the domain account's password as well.

I am thinking that if can manually specify/type in using the keyboard the administrator logon name (i.e. MACHINENAME\ADMINISTRATOR) I should be able to login. But I see to obvious option to do this.

So I guess there are two questions here. 1) What is going on here? 2) Is there a "trick" to manually specify/type in a logon name when there is no obvious way to do so (e.g. press some key combination to force a text field to appear that allows you to input the logon name)?

Also, a side thought, is there a chance that the local administrator account has been disabled? Would this account for the incorrect/weird signin display name?

Here are some some screenshots to give you a better idea of what is going on:

[image]

This is the screen that I see when I first access my local console. It is prompting me to press Ctl+Alt+Del to sign in.

[image]

This is the screen that I see after I press Ctl+Alt+Del. There is an input box for a password. Above the input box is the **display name** (not the netbios name) for the **domain account** that I logged in with after performing the domain joins. The server is currently in a workgroup (i.e. not in a domain). As you can see, there are no visible options to log in with any other account (unlike the screenshots posted below). There are no visible options to manually specify/type in a logon name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is how I solved the problem.

To reiterate, the problem was that for whatever reason I could not select/specify the local administrator account when logging into a stand-alone machine (i.e. in a workgroup). The logon screen would only give me the option to log in with my domain user account, e.g. John Smith.

The solution: start up the machine in safe mode (accessed by pressing F8 during boot up). In safe mode, I was magically given the option to log in using the Administrator account (i.e. no traces of the John Smith domain account).

Answer (score 4):

I did a Google image search and got this:

[image]

[image]

Those images comes from [this article](http://www.elmajdal.net/WindowsServer/How_To_Join_Windows_Server_2012_To_a_Domain.aspx) on how to join a Windows Server 2012 server to a domain.  One of the steps in the article is to change from a local to a domain user.  If you click the arrow, there's an option to enter a different user.

Also:

> Also, a side thought, is there a chance that the local administrator
>   account has been disabled?

If the domain had a policy to cause that, yes.

> Would this account for the incorrect/weird signin display name?

Probably not, IMHO.  I think it's more likely that the server is confused about who logged in last because the domain has changed.

*** edit in response to your edit ***

I'm pretty sure that you need to press control-alt-delete on this screen (your image):

[image]

...to get this screen (edited from your image):

[image]

...and click that arrow to the left of the default picture (which I've put in a red square).  That should get you to a screen where you enter a different user:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your input. When I press the back arrow, I am returned to the signin screen. However, when I press Ctl+Alt+Del I am sent to a screen similar to the screenshot you posted above, except that the signin name shown is the same as the display name from my domain user account. Again, I am not currently joined to a domain--I am in a workgroup. So I guess that there are two strange things going on here: 1) the option to logon as the local administrator does not exist, 2) the option that does exist does not make sense because the user that is displayed does not exist on the local machine.

Comment: It is possible that the display name from the domain account was "mapped" to the local administrator account, but if this is the case, I should be able to log into the local machine using the local administrator password, but I can't.

Comment: I just added a second image from the linked article.  Are you saying that you never get the second screen?  (I'd love a screenshot, but I imagine you can't get one or else you would have provided one.)  Can you remote desktop, or remotely manage the machine from another "workgroup" machine with identical credentials?

Comment: I added links to screenshots above. As far as credentials, the domain account works fine with other machines, but not this one (i.e. because it isn't in a domain). As far as local accounts, there is only the local admin account. However, the name on the signin screen shows the display name for my domain account. I don't know why. I cannot logon using the local admin account password with the displayed login ID. I'm thinking that if I can manually enter <localmachine>\administrator as the logon ID I might be able to logon under the local admin. However, I could be barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to 1. press control-alt-delete, 2. Click the arrow to the left of the pic.  This should give you a place to enter the other username.  I'll mark and edit.

Comment: I appreciate your help and patience. When I press the arrow to the left of the picture I am returned to the Ctl+Alt+Del screen. The image that you posted, the one that shows you the option to select between users including "Other user," does not show up.

Comment: I still see no answer to this problem. Since I can't log in, I guess I'm going to have to recreate this server from scratch. This is a test server so it isn't that big of a deal, but I'd prefer not to have to do this...